# How do you get the "Savior" achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

"Save players from death 250 times"

What are the mechanics? What methods can I use?

Comment: I think the question should be: how low does the player's health has to be before it would count for this achievement.

Comment: There are many factors at play now. See my answer.

Comment: Things have changed again :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this website](http://www.rarityguide.com/articles/articles/2456/1/Diablo-3-Achievement-Guide---Challenges-Achievements/Page1.html) a save is when you

> Deliver the last blow on a monster when another player is at 5%
>   health or less

granted the other player is reasonably close (my guess here is within 1 screen).

Answer (score 3):

If you survive an encounter with less than 5% of your health, you get a "Survived" fanfare (along with a % of your HP that remains).

Saving players would involve killing the last creature in combat whilst a party member is on low HP. Then do this another 249 times.

Comment: Can't be more specific than that at the moment as I have not tested this. This is a speculative answer at this stage.

Comment: I've gotten the message that I've "saved" someone only to have them die instantly afterwards during the same combat. So I don't think this is correct.

Comment: I did say it was speculative

Comment: That's fine, I just wanted to note that it was, in my experience, incorrect.

Comment: @Rapida your "savee" could still die after you killing the last foe, due to poison, which has DoT effect.

Comment: @Bora that's true, but I've seen it in situations where there were no DoTs being used. I think Phillip is on track by saying it is based on per monster rather than last monster in a combat.

Answer (score 3):

*This answer is up to date as of 05/18/2014, game version 2.0.5, and comes from having farmed the achievement right now.*

Getting a **Savior** callout requires:

- having an ally below 5% life,
- killing the last monster that was aggressive towards your wounded ally.

The "victim" player should have two sets of items: one with maximum Life, another with no Vitality at all. Swapping to and from no-vit items brings your health down, though there is some kind of threshold, and your health settles a bit higher than your "naked" health.

Preparation:

1. Killer should turn on Player health bars (*default [D]*), and memorize victim's 5% life number.
2. Victim swaps to and from no-vit gear. This should bring his life low, but likely not below 5%. See last paragraph for staying in range.
3. Killer makes sure the area is clean from shooters, elites, and other dangerous mobs.

Actual farming (we did this in Old Tristram Road with zombies, it is also doable with *Carrion Nests* and endless bats):

1. Victim singles out a monster and aggroes it.
2. After killer is sure the monster is the only one following the victim, he wastes the monster.
3. **BOTH** players get Savior callout.
4. Goto 1.

Every now and then one of the players will inadvertently step on a health globe. The victim has to stay below 5% life, so he should run out and take some hits. On the other hand, dropping too low is also dangerous - if you die and are revived, you'll be at full life and will have to swap again. Ideally, the victim should have a controllable regen gear or healing spells to stay at 4-5%.

Happy farming!